# Assigning "n" to the total number of words detected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

For a current project, I am planning to count the total number of words in a given Pandas DataFrame. The code below is based on SciKit-Learn and assigns a frequency to each word identified but requires to define the total quantity `n` of words considered.

I am however looking to count the total number of words in the DataFrame. Is there any way to set `n` to an infinite number to cover all relevant words in the DataFrame and to then calculate the sum of these relevant words (i.e. not showing `'manager' : 10, 'office': 5` but `'total words': 15`)?

In the given example, I am using `10000` as the number of words to be considered (through the line `common_words1=get_top_n_bigram_Group1(df[i], 100000)`) but am wondering if there is a more flexible/automated way.

The relevant code section looks as follows:

```
# Word frequency analysis
def get_top_n_bigram_Group1(corpus, n=None):
    vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words='english').fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]


for i in ['txt_pro','txt_con','txt_adviceMgmt','txt_main']:
    # Loop over the common words inside the JSON object
    common_words1= get_top_n_bigram_Group1(df[i], 100000)
    common_words1.to_csv('out1.csv')
```

Comment: What are the relevant words? Do you want to include all the words in `words_freq`. If so, then just don't use `n` as a threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The relevant words are all words included in the file. `words_freq` is showing the most frequent words until `n` is reached (i.e. if `n` = 100 it is showing the 100 most frequent words).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your purpose correctly, the following return statement should do the job. You don't need to use `n` at all.

Change this line

```
return words_freq[:n]
```

to this

```
return {'total_words': sum(frequency for word, frequency in words_freq)}
```

Comment: Good thought - I tried it but it is leaving to an empty DataFrame as output....

Comment: Okay, can you elaborate clearly in the question what your desired outputs are? You want the total words. What should be the DataFrame output? Your function does not return a DataFrame.

Comment: I would ideally like an output `'total words' : 23,124`, i.e. an indication of the total number of words present in the text. Apologies if that was not clear